# How do I close an external app like Instagram launched from my app and return to the Triggering App?

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram, android-package-managers

I have an Android App which uses Intent to launch Instagram, to my page. Once the user is done with Instagram and closes it with the back arrow, I need instagram to close and return the user back to my Android App which triggered the activity. my Intent works and opens instagram but with the back button it stays in instagram. Find below my code triggering instgram

```
public void LaunchInstgram(View view){

    Intent openInstagram = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
    openInstagram.setData( Uri.parse( "https://www.instagram.com/_u/eatoutlagos") );
    try {
        startActivity(openInstagram);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, Instagram Not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579725/how-to-get-back-to-initial-app-where-the-implicit-intent-is-started

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling `finish()` method in you `MainActivity` before starting `Instagram` App via `Intents`

The scenario which you have described will occur in following two ways:

EITHER

You have set `android:noHistory = "true"` for `MainActivity` inside `AndroidManifest.xml` which causes `MainActivity` to **finish** automatically on pressing the back key.

OR

Before switching to your `LaunchInstragram`, you have called `finish()` in your MainActivity, which kills it. When you press back button,since no other activity is present in stack to pop, it stays there...

Also you could try ChatHeads on you App by clicking the following [link](https://medium.com/exploring-code/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064)

**EDIT**

try the following code :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/_u/eatoutlagos");
Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

try {
    startActivity(likeIng);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/_u/eatoutlagos")));
}
```

Comment: hi Amit, I dont seem to be able to get the first two options working. At which stage in  my mainActivity do i put the finish() method? If i put it in the onCreate method it doesnt start the activity at all when i click the button to start. I put it in the method that launches the instagram intent and there is not change, instagram still doesnt close back to my app

Comment: public void LaunchInstgram(View view){
        finish();
        Intent openInstagram = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
        openInstagram.setData( Uri.parse( "https://www.instagram.com/_u/eatoutlagos") );
        try {
       startActivity(openInstagram);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, Instagram Not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/eatoutlagos"

Comment: in the second case I have put the command in the manifest file within the activity that launches the Intagram app as below  <activity android:name=".ContactUs"
            android:noHistory = "true"/>

Comment: but it has no effect. I am not writing the code correctly? please have a look at what i have shared

Comment: You have not read my answer properly.. I said to remove the lines if present...  Not to add them... Also don't comment any codes.  It's not easy to read.. update your question for clarity.. by editing it....

Comment: ok i have re-read your comments and understand. I have not done any of the points you called out to check i.e. I dont have finish() or the code in my Android Manifest. thanks

Comment: Instead of `startActivity` use `startActivityForResult`. You can even `Override` `onActivityResult` method to know **when the user returned from other activity.**

Comment: complete desciption with code here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Comment: i  changed the startActivity to  startActivityForResult(openInstagram, 1); and also used the Override onActivityResult using the following code inside this method if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
               finish();
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }
        }  it still is not producing the desired results. stays in Instgram.

Comment: check out this SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505941/intent-to-open-instagram-user-profile-on-android